# Is it possible to pass data needed for driving directions to the Bing Maps website?

Tags: bing-maps

I have an application that currently links to Google Maps passing it the required URL parameters needed to show driving directions for a set of points (typically 3+).  This approach has worked and has allowed us to not use their API, which worked fine.

With Google, they made it pretty easy and clear by using parameters like "saddr" for the starting address, "to" for way points, and "daddr" for the destination.  I could even pass in "pw" if I wanted to put the map into print mode.  Simple, easy, works great!

I'm trying to determine if Bing Maps supports the same thing.  I have been unable thus far to find any examples showing how this can be done, nor have I been able to easily decode the URL after creating my own driving directions using Bing Maps.

Again, I'd like to avoid using the API and am find with sending users to Bing's site when clicking my link.

It this possible?  If yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

And I just wrote a little blog post to demonstrate how: http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/url-parameters-for-the-bing-maps-website/

Comment: Thanks!  Now I wonder if you can decipher the link once you opt to print the map you just built.  Seems like there are some shared features like the rtp waypoint lists but it seems to also put some extra junk at the end.

Comment: Ricky at Microsoft just sent me through a URL link to a more complete list of parameters: http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/ff808440.aspx

Comment: Thanks, both your post and the help link are very helpful.  Solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Alastair's answer has full details if you follow the link through to the blog post.

But if you want the quick answer (again, thanks Alastair) use this root:

`http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?where1=`

and stick your search destination in  at the end. Eg. this gets you to Atwood Rd in London using its postcode:

http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?where1=W6%200HX